# How do I get a variable to increase every time I run "return main();"

Tags: c++, variables

I need my `Level` to increase by 1 every time I use `return main();`

I need something where I don't set my variables in `int main()`, or that it bypasses the `level = 0;` every time but the first, but I have no idea what to do.

If there are some coding wizards out there, I would greatly appreciate it if you were to help me (oh yea, I replaced `Level` in the welcome message with `"placeholder"`).

I tried making a new file, putting it above the `int main() {}`, using variables to make it when it finishes the code before it goes to the beginning it sets it to 1 so that it only sets `level` to 0 if the other variable (let's call it `reset`) is 1, but that didn't work because the `reset` to 0 every time it does it starts again. That didn't work, so I got rid of it.

```
int main()
{
    int level;
    level = 0;

    system("cls");
    //varibles

    int secret, guess;
    // color
    SetConsoleTextAttribute(GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE), 4);

    //the number that you guess!
    srand(time(NULL));
    secret = rand() % 100 - 0;

    cout << "   Number Guessing Game!" << endl;
    cout << "----------------------------------" << endl;
    cout << endl;
    SetConsoleTextAttribute(GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE), 6);
    cout << "Welcome my name is Luffy Computron. your currant level is " << "placeholder" << endl;
    cout << " I will randomly pick a number between 0 and 100" << endl;
    SetConsoleTextAttribute(GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE), 22);
    cout << "Take a guess" << endl;
    SetConsoleTextAttribute(GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE), 2);
    cout << "Guess:";
    cin >> guess;
    while (guess != secret) {
        if (guess > secret) {
            SetConsoleTextAttribute(GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE), 6);
            cout << "Too large. Try again." << endl;
            SetConsoleTextAttribute(GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE), 2);
        }
        if (guess < secret) {
            SetConsoleTextAttribute(GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE), 6);
            cout << "Too small. Try again." << endl;    
            SetConsoleTextAttribute(GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE), 2);
        }
        cout << "Guess:";
        cin >> guess;
    }

    if (guess == secret) {
        SetConsoleTextAttribute(GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE), 6);
        cout << "Congradulations!" << endl;
        if (level == 1) {
            cout << "you are now an untrained aprentice of the computron team";
            cout << "to become an aprentice play 4 more times!";
        }
    }
    Sleep(2000);
    return main();
}
```

It's supposed to change `level` by one every time it runs `return main();`
but it just stays at 1.

Comment: Use a loop.  `return main();` is illegal as *thou shalt not call `main()`*

Comment: I don't see any other `return` statement in `main`. Do you not want your program to exit gracefully ever?

Comment: [Currant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ribes) level? Sounds delicious.

Comment: it will never end! @RSahu

Comment: Unrelated: Why `-0` in `secret = rand() % 100 - 0;`?

Comment: How would I use a loop @NathanOliver

Comment: Pretty much the same as you did in `while (guess != secret)`, but with a different exit condition.

Comment: It's a random number between 100 and 0

Comment: ok I can work from that

Comment: thank you @NathanOliver

Comment: ummmm that didn't work

Comment: You'll have to bump the divisor up by 1 to get 0..100. you can't divide by 100 and get a remainder of 100.

Comment: it just spammed in the console "Guess: Too small. Try again.

Comment: Never mind it worked thank you I forgot to get rid of the return main();

Answer (score 5):

Do not call `main()`. Use a loop around what you'd like to repeat:

```
int main() {
    bool running = true;
    int level = 0;

    while(running) {

        //...

        ++level;
    } // <- your old return main(); replaced with }
}
```

This will loop between `while(running) {` and the `}` marked in the code until you change `running` to `false`. You can also use `break;` to exit the closest surrounding loop, like this:

```
    while(true) {
        if(some_condition) break;
    }
```

> It's supposed to change level by one every time it runs return main();
>   but it just stays at 1.

In your current code, you assign `level = 0;` at the start of `main()`. By using loop like above that assignment will only happen once.

Comment: Or use `while (true) { ... }` and then use `break;` to leave the loop. (IMHO that's the better alternative because pretty much anything is better than state variables for control flow.)